# dismiss searchDisplayController with searchbar not working

Tags: ios, iphone, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I try to dismiss the searchDisplayController of my master-detail view. So i tried a lot and googleing around but nothing works for me.

```
self.searchDisplayController.active = NO;
```

The situation i have is, that the ui needs to jump to a cell in a table (master view) from the selected detail-view using html-links.

Touching to the link need to update the master-view and scroll to the table-entry and open it's detail-view.

When i'm using the searchbar before and then touch a link everthing works fine but when i'm touch the back button of the detail-view the searchbar and it's overlay is still visible (see image below). Why?

The following message appears:

```
Snapshotting a view (0x7ff350e67080, UIInputSetHostView) that has not
been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.
```

[image]

Comment: Did you solve in the end? I also get the same message.

Comment: @aneuryzm i think is better to remove the UISearchDisplayController and replace it with the UISearchController, this solves also the iOS 13 Bugs for me. Regards